# ajaxForm - "uploadProgress" shows progress even though php to upload file does not exist

Tags: php, ajax, file, upload

I created a form with a file upload progress bar. I am using ajaxForm to set pre/post actions. Once the upload process has ended, I want to generate a new web page and send email by calling “sendEmail.php”. The problem is that I can see to progress file reaching 100% but nothing happens after that. It is stuck on 100%
I have 2 question:

1. when I was testing this I noticed that the action -"UPLOAD.php" was missing and yet I saw a progress bar which was behaving proportionally to the files size.
   why is that? what was uploading the file?
2. when I add the UPLOAD.php it was still not working.

My form creation line looks like this:

```
<form id="formmail" class="form-horizontal col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-sm-offset-1" name="formmail" method="POST" action="**UPLOAD.php**" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

My script to generate the progress bar:

```
var progress

$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        $("#formmail").ajaxForm({
            type: "POST",
            url: "sendEmail.php",
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#progressBar").removeClass("hidden");
                progress = "0%";
                $('.progress-bar').css("width", progress);
                $('.progress-bar').html(progress);
            },
            uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                progress = percentComplete + "%";
                $('.progress-bar').css("width", progress);
                $('.progress-bar').html(progress);  
            },
            success: function (data){
                alert("It's OK!");
            },
        }).submit();
    });
});
```

The PHP to upload the file, in this case only upload. I will move the file once it is working.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_FILES['fileatt']['name'])){
    $tmp = $_FILES['fileatt']['tmp_name'];
    echo "echo something";
?>
```

Comment: When you don't set the action for a form, it defaults to the current web page.  The file is uploaded whether that page can handle it or not, which is why you saw the progress based on the file size.  What is the `print_r()` result for `$_FILES`?  To see it, you may need to `file_put_contents` the data (remember to set the second argument of `print_r()` to `true` or the data won't be saved to the file.

Comment: thank you,
i'm new to this - could you be more specific please, perhaps a short example?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer so much as it's an extended comment...

We need to know if the uploaded file is actually arriving.  Therefore, make this the first line of your upload.php file.

```
file_put_contents('upload_test.txt', print_r($_FILES,true));
```

I'm assuming that your web server has write permissions to the directory where upload.php is executed.  If not, you'll need to give a path to a directory it can write to.  Usually, the directory above DOCUMENT_ROOT can be written to.

If the upload is utterly failing (no file is received), you'll see an empty array.  If it is succeeding, you'll see the uploaded file name and a bunch of other information.  If it's succeeding, the problem is simply one of handling the file properly.